# I changed the name of the id in cshtml, now how would I pass it to the controller using begin form

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

1. It is for a delete modal and the page I'm working on is being rendered to another page. L also have edit modal which perfectly works.

   2. in the delete form I changed id name `PositionId` to `PositionIdDelete`. I was able to set the right value to `PositionIdDelete` to pass to controller
   3. `using html.beginform(“Delete”,”Positions”,new {id=what??},FormMethod.Post)`.
      how would I write `PositionIdDelete` to pass
   4. `@Model.PositionId` won't work for this because its default value is zero when the page loads
2. there is a table of `Position` in this view and that is where I get the id, and again I was able to pass it to `PositionIdDelete` through javascript, checked it through DOM, it's there.
3. now since I changed the `PositionId` id name to another id name how would I put it as a parameter

This is my code

```
    <div class="modal-body">
    <p style="text-align:justify;">Are you sure you want to delete '<p id="pPositionNameDelete"></p>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "Positions", new { id="??? WHAT TO PUT HERE  ???"},FormMethod.Post))
                {
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PositionId,new { id= "PositionIdDelete" })

                    <div class="form-actions no-color">
                        <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-default" />

                    </div>
                }
       </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Model.PositionId shouldn't be a zero. 
Try to pass this Id from action. It would be a better practice.

Comment: i can do that but the problem is, the value is supposed to change when i click a link from a table that changes the PositionId.

Comment: my question is how can i pass the value of the PositionId after changing its id name

Comment: @YangyangCobarrubias as i understood the value of hidden PositionId changes. If yes, just don't pass anything in BeginForm() and get value on the controller from model.